# Matching column names in DB using JOIN NULL values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create an "eBay" style category menu where when the user selects an item from a multiselect field it will add a new multiselect with any sub categories and if the sub category contains sub categories add a new multi select with the sub sub categories.

I have this mostly working but I am having trouble with the database side of things. I have a main table called `categories` that contains two columns `CatID` and `Category`. There are three rows in the `categories` table "Motorcycles", "Powersports" and "Parts & Accessories"

When a user selects Motorcycles it should create a new multi select and bring up Motorcycle Brands. If on the other hand the user selects Powersports it should create a new multi dropdown and list Powersport vehicle types "Dirtbike", "PWC", "Snowmobile" etc. Which upon selecting one of those will bring up a Powersports->Vehicle Type->Brand multiselect.

The problem is I don't know how to reference all of this information properly in the database.

For example:
Main Categories(categories)

```
+-------+---------------------+
| CatID | Category            |
+-------+---------------------+
|     1 | Motorcycles         |
|     3 | Parts & Accessories |
|     2 | Powersports         |
+-------+---------------------+
```

Motorcycles Sub Category: (motorcycle_brands)

```
+-------+-------+-------------------------+
| CatID | SubID | SubName                 |
+-------+-------+-------------------------+
|     1 |     1 | American Classic Motors |
|     1 |     2 | American Ironhorse      |
|     1 |     3 | Aprilia                 |
|     1 |     4 | Benelli                 |
|     1 |     5 | Big Dog                 |
+-------+-------+-------------------------+
```

Power Sports Sub Category: (powersport_categories)

```
+-------+-------+--------------------------------+----+
| CatID | SubID | SubName                        | ID |
+-------+-------+--------------------------------+----+
|     2 |     1 | ATVs                           |  1 |
|     2 |     2 | Dune Buggies / Sand Rails      |  2 |
|     2 |     3 | Go Karts: High-Performance     |  3 |
|     2 |     4 | Personal Watercraft            |  4 |
|     2 |     5 | Powersport Vehicles Under 50cc |  5 |
+-------+-------+--------------------------------+----+
```

So if I run the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM categories C 
LEFT JOIN motorcycle_brands MB ON MB.CatID = C.CatID 
LEFT JOIN powersport_categories PC ON PC.CatID = C.CatID 
WHERE C.CatID = 1 LIMIT 5;
```

I get this:

```
+-------+-------------+-------------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------+-------+---------+------+
| CatID | Category    | CatDBTable        | CatID | SubID | SubName                 | CatID | SubID | SubName | ID   |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------+-------+---------+------+
|     1 | Motorcycles | motorcycle_brands |     1 |     1 | American Classic Motors |  NULL |  NULL | NULL    | NULL |
|     1 | Motorcycles | motorcycle_brands |     1 |     2 | American Ironhorse      |  NULL |  NULL | NULL    | NULL |
|     1 | Motorcycles | motorcycle_brands |     1 |     3 | Aprilia                 |  NULL |  NULL | NULL    | NULL |
|     1 | Motorcycles | motorcycle_brands |     1 |     4 | Benelli                 |  NULL |  NULL | NULL    | NULL |
|     1 | Motorcycles | motorcycle_brands |     1 |     5 | Big Dog                 |  NULL |  NULL | NULL    | NULL |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------+-------+---------+------+
```

Notice all the NULL values at the end. Is there a way to get rid of these null values? It is causing other problems in my code because when it returns this array back to my PHP script the `SubID` and `SubName` array fields are blank since it goes with the last set which are NULL. However if I run the same query as above replacing 1 with 2 then I get the values I want back since they are not over written by duplicate column names.

Maybe I am going about this all wrong I was planning on having the same `SubID` and `SubName` columns in all of my tables for sub categories but it looks like it may cause me grief. The reason I did this is because otherwise I was having to write a separate query depending on what value was selected I wanted to have basically one query that would do it all essentially for each sub option. Is there any improvements here?

Comment: instead of `*` try the specific column names you want in select query

Answer (score 1):

1) Try something like this (you should also check my other point below):

```
SELECT C.CatID, C.Category, C.CatDBTable, MB.SubID AS MbSubID, MB.SubName AS MbSubName, PC.SubID AS PcSubID, PC.SubName AS PcSubName, PC.ID AS PcID FROM categories C 
LEFT JOIN motorcycle_brands MB ON MB.CatID = C.CatID 
LEFT JOIN powersport_categories PC ON PC.CatID = C.CatID 
WHERE C.CatID = 1 LIMIT 5;
```

2) Your database structure might be made better and more extensible (if you needed for exemple to add a 4th degree sub) if you used the following approach :

Have only one table name categories which has the following columns :

- ID
- parent_id (nullable)
- depth
- name

you will use it as follows:

- "Motorcycles" which is a main category will have: (ID => 1, parent_id => null, depth => 0, name => Motorcycles)
- "American Classic Motors" which is a sub of "Motorcycles" will have: (ID => 4, parent_id => 1, depth => 1, name => American Classic Motors)
- "ATVs" which is a sub of "American Classic Motors" will have: (ID => 5, parent_id => 4, depth => 2, name => ATVs)

Comment: I had thought about a structure similar to your second answer but I think it might be harder to maintain. I think it would be easier just to have separate tables for each category, subCat, subSubCat, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT C.CatID,C.Category,MB.CatID as MBCatID,MB.SubID as MBSubID,MB.SubName as MBSubName,IFNULL(PC.CatID,'') as PCCatID,IFNULL(PC.SubID,'') as PcSubID,IFNULL(PC.SubName,'') as PcSubName,IFNULL(PC.ID,'') as PCID FROM categories C 
    LEFT JOIN motorcycle_brands MB ON MB.CatID = C.CatID 
    LEFT JOIN powersport_categories PC ON PC.CatID = C.CatID 
    WHERE C.CatID = 1 LIMIT 5;
```

See the result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13c25/8)